# Validating Data Entry

Tags: vb.net, validation

This seems like such a poor way of validating data entry. Something that I find myself doing a lot. Is there a way the procedures can be combined or simplified?

Sub Main()
...

```
  Console.Write("Landscape Size: ")
                IsNumeric(LandscapeSize)
                Console.Write("Initial number of warrens: ")
                IsNumeric(InitialWarrenCount)
                Validate(InitialWarrenCount, LandscapeSize)
                Console.Write("Initial number of foxes: ")
                IsNumeric(InitialFoxCount)
                Validate(InitialFoxCount, LandscapeSize)
```

And here are the two subs which seem overly complex:

```
    Sub IsNumeric(ByRef Variable As Integer)
    While True
        Try
            Variable = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
            Exit While
        Catch
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter a number:")
        End Try
    End While
End Sub
Sub Validate(ByVal Variable As Integer, ByVal LandscapeSize As Integer)
    Dim Size As Integer
    Size = (LandscapeSize * LandscapeSize)
    While Variable <= 0 Or Variable >= Size
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter a number:")
        While True
            Try
                Variable = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
                Exit While
            Catch
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter a number:")
            End Try
        End While
    End While
End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: I don't see a lot you can change there... Maybe a few lines you can combine but it won't help you any.

Comment: Two comments: 1. Don't use the name IsNumeric.. that's a reserved system function name. 2. Using try/catch to trap non numeric is not the best way to do that. Error handling has a LARGE overhead associated with it. You are better to read a string and test it with the system function IsNumeric().

Comment: @Trevor In a way, I'm sort of pleased you said that. It just seemed so laborious to have two try catch statements. Thank you. Edit - so declare as string and use IsNumeric..that sounds better...

Comment: Use Integer.TryParse.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its asking for a review. `Is there a way the procedures can be combined or simplified`, there sure is and ***this site is not for that***. [**Code Review Stack Exchange**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is where you need to visit...

Comment: I didn't even know that one existed @Zaggler

Comment: SO should make that way more VISIBLE on the page.... @Zaggler

Comment: I agree, but there's a site for this type of request. SO is for helping with specific programming related issues, not reviewing. It helps keep these types of requests separate and the sites more relevant to what they are for.

Comment: I understand @Zaggler ... but I don't appreciate getting a down vote for helping someone either.... esp when the code review should be up front on the page.

Comment: I don't appreciate down votes either, but it happens. Maybe you should ask in your post why the reason for the down vote and maybe they will leave a comment or maybe they have not left one yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So rename the IsNumeric..
Get rid of the try catch using TryParse instead

```
Sub ReadNumber(ByRef Variable As Integer)
  Do
      If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), variable) Then Exit Sub
      Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter a number:")
  Loop
End Sub

Sub Validate(ByVal Variable As Integer, ByVal LandscapeSize As Integer)
    Dim Size As Integer = LandscapeSize * LandscapeSize
    While Variable <= 0 Or Variable >= Size
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter a number:")
        do
            If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), variable) Then Exit Do
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter a number:")
        loop
    End While
End Sub
```

HOWEVER.. I'm guessing you really wanted that first variable in the Validate to be ByRef NOT ByVal.

Comment: I am very grateful. TryParse seems like a more efficient method. Thank you.